# Remove gradient text hover css

Tags: html, css

Please tell me how to make the text color blue when hovering?
Thank you in advance)

```css
span {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 255, 19, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 209, 255, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms;
}

span:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span>Hover</span>
```

Comment: replace `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` with `color: transparent;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, write an answer, I will accept